# .htaccess and google crawl bug

Tags: .htaccess, seo, web-crawler

I'm having trouble  with this website since I've added a .htaccess file. Google bot doesn't crawl the new links.

here is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.grantsimeonphoto.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule    ^accueil$     index.php?page=accueil
RewriteRule    ^services$    index.php?page=services
RewriteRule    ^portfolio$   index.php?page=portfolio
RewriteRule    ^contact$     index.php?page=contact
RewriteRule    ^epreuves$    index.php?page=epreuves
```

if you make a search on google you will see :

```
site:grantsimeonphoto.com

here is my robot.txt:
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Here is my sitemap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<url>
  <loc>http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/</loc>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/accueil</loc>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/services</loc>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/portfolio</loc>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/contact</loc>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/epreuves</loc>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Not an answer, but your robots.txt is not configured as there is no `allow` only `disallow`. So your syntax should be:  `disallow: ` (with nothing following it). Additionally, you could reference your XML sitemap inside the robot.txt for additional exposure.

Comment: even though Allow is not in the basic robots.txt spec, Allow is still commonly used (and understood by google) i.e.: http://www.google.com/robots.txt so that is not the issue

Comment: hi, could is just be, that the .htaccess redirects do not work, see: http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/index.php?page=services HTTP 200 , http://www.grantsimeonphoto.com/accueil HTTP 404 ... so google won't index the new pages, as they are HTTP 404.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the allow, commonly all search engines will crawl your links when it doesn't explicitly disallow the specified URL.